# How to add libaries to pycharm manually

Tags: python, pycharm

So, In pycharm(and python 3.7.4), ssl is not supported. And it keeps causing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-reqv02n_\ssl\setup.py", line 33
    print 'looking for', f
                      ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
```

So, I used the link "https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/ssl.py" to get the file and included this python file in the same folder where I want to import ssl. Would this work? or otherwise, how could I use ssl in python3? (p. s. I'm using windwos 10)

Comment: odd, this looks like version 2 of python: printing without parentheses. Are you sure you are using 3.7.4 in PyCharm? Check your project interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3, you cannot make a `print` statement without parenthesis. In python 2, you are able to do something like `print "hello"` but in python 3 you must use parenthesis, `print ("hello")`

If you want to use python 2, please change your virtual environment in your project interpreter to be Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is the error of missing parenthesis. You have to use print("looking for", f) in python 3